# javascript Refresh Div

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code to refresh the data inside of the div:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function() {
     $("#new").load("/new.php")
  })
})
</script>
```

Except it loads the who page inside of the div, instead of just the information that is inside of the div.

How do I make it refresh only the data that is inside of the div? Is there a way of doing it other than putting the information for that div in a seperate page?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with this line: "Except it loads the who page inside of the div, instead of just the information that is inside of the div." ? I'm struggling to make sense of it...sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that new.php is a script that returns the entire page, the answer is no.

You have to send just the html fragment you need for refreshing the div.

You can always get the result from new.php, take the good part and discard the rest but it is inefficent.

Answer (score 0):

You can load page fragments with 'load'. Say the information you need is inside a div called "#info" on new.php, change the load line to this:

`$("#new").load("/new.php #info")`

Answer (score 0):

If you were refreshing data from the server you have to reload the whole page/frame (you could request the client to cache images, CSS, etc.) or use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).